# How to send nonchecked checkbox to post

Tags: php, html, post

Only my checkboxes that are checked are being put into $_POST. I would like for the ones that are checked to be in $_POST with a value of 'true' and the non checked ones to have a value of 'false.' Is there anyway to do this or will the POST request always only contain info about checked checkboxes.

The only thing I can think of is to use hidden form fields and just have the checkboxes manipulate those.

Comment: you could just create an array of the names of the checkboxes on the php side and loop through it to see if they were `$_POST`ed, if so, they are true else, they're false.

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid : ), since I have a ton of checkboxes that are pulled from an XML file I don't really want to read the XML file once to display and once to compare the results

Comment: unless it's an absolutely massive xml file or you haven't put the parsing of the xml file into a function, it should be very straight forward to read the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Posting Unchecked Checkbox](http://planetozh.com/blog/2008/09/posting-unchecked-checkboxes-in-html-forms/) and [Unchecked checkbox values](http://planetozh.com/blog/go.php?http://iamcam.wordpress.com/2008/01/15/unchecked-checkbox-values/)

It is possible by adding hidden fields with same name.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" name="myCheckbox" value="false" />
```

and then parse the input on the server.  You'll either get `false` or `true false`, the former maps to `false` and the latter maps to `true`

Answer (score 0):

it will only contain content of checked checkboxes. you have to emulate that otherwise by using a form helper or an input filter that wires your variables / arrays the way you like it.

such functionality will need all checkboxes you use per form and can then set to true whats found and leave at false whats not detected.

Answer (score 0):

you could from your php do:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])||$_POST['checkbox']!="yes"){
    //other code here
}
```

or, you could have some javascript to add a hidden input before submit for checkbox values that are not being sent

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, since it's browser dependend.

You can just check if it's posted by doing

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['checkbox1']))
{
    // it's posted
}
```

Or use `!`:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['checkbox1']))
{
    // it's NOT posted
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assume in your server-side that those who are not set on the post data, are unchecked. Try to verify if the variable is set:

```
$_POST['a_checkbox'] = (isset($_POST['a_checkbox'])) ? 1 : 0;
```

Use `true` and `false`, or data ase needed.